# Correctly Calculate $\sin(\mathrm{arc\,cot}(x)) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm attempting to calculate $\sin(\mathrm{arc\,cot}(x))$.

I know that:
$$\
\theta = \mathrm{arc\,cot}({\frac x1})
$$

where$\ x$ is adjacent to $\theta$ and$\ 1$ is opposite to $\theta$.

$$\
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\to c = \sqrt{x^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + 1}
$$

[image: right triangle with lengths]

Now plug into $\sin$:

$$\
\sin\theta={\frac{\mathrm{opp}}{\mathrm{hyp}}}
= {\frac {1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}}
= {\frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}}
$$

$$\
\to \sin(\mathrm{arc\,cot}(x))={\frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}}
$$

However I have a table that lists the solution as:

$$\
\sin(\mathrm{arc\,cot}(x))={\frac {1}{x \sqrt{{\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}}}
$$

**My question is:** how does one go from:
$$\
{\frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}}
\to
{\frac {1}{x \sqrt{{\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}}}
$$

I'm quite sure the two expressions are equal, but I'm lacking the algebra skills to simplify.

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin%28arccot%28x%29%29) provides the correct result, however [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/trigonometry-calculator/sin%5Cleft(arccot%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5Cright)?or=input) does not simplify.

Comment: Your second sentence makes no sense.

Comment: I am not sure about the solution you mention. In fact $\sin(\mbox{arccot} x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-\arctan x\right) = \cos\arctan x$ is an even function while the solution you mention is not.

Comment: @TedShifrin I replaced it with a picture. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: No, your second sentence ($\text{arccot}(1/x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}$) just makes no sense. The arccot function gives an angle, not a hypotenuse of a triangle.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, I see your point. I'm kinda lazy with my notation on paper. Until I wrote this question I've never written math for other people to consume. Well since high school and that was over 20 years ago. I'll get the question fixed up when I get to my desktop.

Comment: No problem. I hope you'll find that my answer shows you how to phrase things carefully and understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{x\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}}=\frac1{x\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}}}=\frac1{x*\frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}$$When $x>0$. If $x<0$, then put a negative sign in front of the RHS.

Comment: This is wrong. The right-hand side is always positive, whereas the left-hand side is negative when $x<0$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+1\right)}}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}$$If $x>0$.

Answer (score 3):

For any $x\in\Bbb R$, $\text{arccot}(x)$ is the number (angle) $\theta$ in $(0,\pi)$ with $\cot(\theta) = x$. So think of a right triangle with horizontal edge $x$ (which might be negative) and height $1$. It's hypotenuse is $\sqrt{x^2+1}$. Then $\sin\theta = \dfrac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. Note that it is always positive, since $\theta$ is in $(0,\pi)$ and the sin function is positive on that interval.

Answer (score 1):

${\frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}}$
$={\frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}}×{\frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$ $={\frac {{x^2+1}}{x^2+1\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$ $=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$
Now take common $x^2$ from denominator
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{1}{x^2}})}$ $=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}$ $=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}$

$ \forall   x>0$

Comment: This is wrong. You need $|x|$.

Comment: @tedshifrin what's wrong with it can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes. $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. Note that your expression is negative when $x<0$ (and not defined at $x=0$, obviously.

Comment: @tedshifrin I think In this question we have to use principal square root as in trigonometry most of the cases we use only positive value so

Comment: Absolutely not true (pun intended). In trigonometry, you must *definitely* pay attention to signs. Think about the signs of the trigonometric functions as you go from quadrant to quadrant; those are crucial.

Comment: @tedshifrin we have to pay attention for quadrant to quadrant but in square root most of the cases we use positive value then see in which quadrant angle lie

Comment: Not true. Look at the formulas for the derivatives of $\text{arcsec}$ and $\text{arccsc}$. Why are there absolute values in there?

Comment: I am talking about in trigonometry simply when we apply Pythagoras theorem or pythagorean identity then why we use simple positive value after that we use sign according to Angle lie in which quadrant

Comment: By the way I also got your point you are right

Comment: Even just doing trigonometric functions themselves, the signs are very important. Think about $\cos 2x$ when you go from certain $x$ in the first quadrant to $2x$ in the second quadrant.

Comment: Yes you are right I got your point because there was not mention angle lies in which quadrant so I take it principle square root but you are absolutely correct on your point of view and concept

Comment: @IbrarTahir thanks for your answer. I updated the question to make it explicit this problem is in Q1.